# Pandoc longtable and full width formatting

Tags: longtable, pandoc

I need an example how to set a newenvironment (if that is the way) for longtable with Pandoc for formatting columns and/or the whole table as fullwith depending on line length or paper settings.

In the .tex file only \usepackage{longtable} is set. It tried a few things like adding

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}

\setlength\LTright{0p}

but without any effect. I start writing academic papers with Pandoc and Latex and need help.

Thank you

Comment: you need `{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}` or similar to add stretchy space to make up for removing stretch from the left and right

Comment: I testet it without luck, but will give it another try. Thanks for your help.